# Number of cluster variables associated to A type quivers

Tags: quivers, cluster-algebras

In a seminar/reading course about cluster algebras, we came across the fact that the number of cluster variables for the cluster algebra associated to mutating the quiver $A_n$ is $n(n+3)/2$ (rather, we verified it for small $n$, and my professor said this should be the answer, because of some Lie theory). It was noted that this sequence coincides (up to shifting the index) with the number of chambers in a wiring diagram (for the maximal length element of $S_n$), and with the number of diagonals in a regular $n$-gon.

We pose the question: are these relationships coincidences?

We know that there are cluster algebras associated to wiring diagrams + braid moves, and to triangulation by diagonals + flips. But in the case of an polygon, the diagonals only give you some, not all, of the associated cluster variables, so the answer can't be that simple.

Thanks!

Comment: The diagonals do give you all of the cluster variables. See Section 12.2 of Fomin Zelevinsky "Cluster algebras II: Finite type classification" (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208229). Or maybe I'm somehow misunderstanding your question...

Comment: Oops, you're right, that slipped over my head earlier today. And I suppose you can always choose a triangulation so that the dual quiver is type A? That solves that question.

Comment: I don't think "number of chambers in a wiring diagram for $w_0$ has any deep meaning here, but I'm not sure. The cluster variables are in bijection with the almost positive roots, meaning the positive roots together with the number of negative simple roots. The number of the former is $\ell(w_0)$, which is the number of crossings in a wiring diagram for $w_0$ (concretely, $\binom{n}{2}$). The number of the latter is the rank, which can be thought of as the number of horizontal levels between wires in the wiring diagram (concretely, $n-1$).

Comment: You could biject the $\binom{n}{2} + (n-1)$ with chambers by corresponding each crossing to the chamber to its right, and the remaining $n-1$ levels with the chambers that are open to the left, but I don't know if that means anything.

Comment: @SamHopkins you're right, but I wasn't thinking about it quite right. In any case, the quiver associated to a triangulation (as we know it, following https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05735) has some frozen nodes and some mutable nodes. Why then should we be getting the same number of cluster variables as for the A_n quiver (which has no frozen nodes)?

Comment: The number of cluster variables, and the combinatorics of the cluster complex more generally, doesn't depend on the frozen variables. That should be in CA4 I think ...

Comment: Without being overly philosophical, and to follow up David's question, what to you distinguishes "any old" bijection from one with some meaning? (As in, what makes something not a coincidence?)

Comment: Another take might be that many cluster algebras (but not all) have geometric, combinatorial or categorical models. So this is a widespread phenomenon and part of a bigger picture, this not coincidental. E.g. surface models for other Lie types than just A - type A combinatorics does appear in many places and sometimes the induced bijection is just coincidental (lots of things have associated quadratic forms) and just because two things are counted by Catalan numbers doesn't mean they're in a natural bijection. But if you can also do types D and E, or even BCFG, this does suggest structure.

Comment: @JanGrabowski I guess by "not a coincidence" we mean that there is a conceptual explanation, particularly relating to cluster algebras. For instance, I am sufficiently satisfied by the explanation for the polygons.

Comment: But wiring diagrams govern the combinatorics of a completely different kind of cluster algebra than the one associated to the $A_n$ quiver...

Comment: @SamHopkins I and the rest of my class are aware of that. Furthermore the number of chambers isn't counting the number of cluster variables for that algebra anyway. That's the main motivation for asking our question. Is there some deeper connection, or just a coincidence that two things happen to have the same count (even if there is some smart bijection like David gave)

Comment: That makes sense, I just think the answer to that part of your question (unlike the part about triangulations) is likely to be "it's a numerical coincidence without any deeper meaning."

Comment: @DavidESpeyer is what you said about cluster combinatorics not depending on frozen nodes implied by Lemma 3.3.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05735? I think it says essentially the same thing, but I want to make sure

Comment: That shows that there is a natural surjection from cluster variables in $\mathcal{A}(B_{\circ})$ to cluster variables in $\mathcal{A}(B'_{\circ})$, but I want the stronger statement that this surjection is a bijection. (In other words, the specialization described here doesn't make two cluster variables become equal if they weren't equal before.)